# Can we say $TT^{*}=T^{2}$ implies $T=T^{*}$?

Tags: operator-theory, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a $C^{*}$-algebra, Can we say  $TT^{*}=T^{2}$ implies $T^{*}=T$? for $T\in A$

I am looking for a counterexample!

Thanks

Comment: If $T$ is normal then using the continuous functional calculus you can prove the statement. Therefore if there is any counterexample for this statement, it should be a non-normal element.

Comment: @VahidShirbisheh I think it is correct for every operators in every algebras!!

Comment: it is my conjecture but i dont know how to prove!

Answer (score 5):

Via a faithful state, we can think of $A$ as represented in some $B(H)$. We have $$ H=\ker T\oplus \overline{\text{ran} T^*}. $$

For $x\in\ker T$, we have $Tx=0$ and then
$$
\|T^*x\|^2=\langle T^*x,T^*x\rangle=\langle TT^*x,x\rangle=\langle T^2x,x\rangle=0;
$$
so $T^*x=0$ and $T=T^*$ on $\ker T$.

Taking adjoints on $TT^*=T^2$ we have $TT^*=T^*T^*$, that is $(T-T^*)T^*=0$. This shows that $T-T^*=0$ on $\text{ran}\,T^*$, and by continuity on its closure. That is, $T=T^*$ on $\overline{\text{ran}\,T^*}$.

So $T=T^*$ on all of $H$.

Comment: On B(H) you are right! But I mean every arbitrary $C^{*}$-algebra

Comment: @Vahid Every $C^*$-algebra is isomorphic to some $C^*$-subalgebra of some $B(H)$. See [GNS Construction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfand%E2%80%93Naimark%E2%80%93Segal_construction)

Comment: @Luiz Cordeiro but we can not prove the above solution for every $C^{*}$-algebra

Comment: @Vahid: yes we can.